# How to interpret multipart that’s missing a CRLF?

Tags: multipartform-data

Here’s a [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1) multipart octet stream that uses a boundary of "boundary".

```
--boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="US-ASCII"

abc

--boundary

a
--boundary


--boundary

--boundary
--boundary--
```

Part 1 is `abc\r\n` with a trailing CRLF and one header describing its content-type.

Part 2 is `a` with no headers and no trailing newline.

Part 3 is empty.

What is part 4? Is there a part 5?

Comment: Jetty 9.4 and Bouncy castle 1.65 interpret it the 4th part as empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I cannot provide a definite answer, this would be my reasoning, based on the RFC:

Following the BNF from [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#page-43), the last part of the example (i.e. OP's "part 4" and "part 5") could be summarized as

```
delimiter CRLF delimiter close-delimiter
```

where `delimiter := CRLF dash-boundary`.
The BNF for the multipart body is defined as

```
multipart-body := [preamble CRLF]
                  dash-boundary transport-padding CRLF
                  body-part *encapsulation
                  close-delimiter transport-padding
                  [CRLF epilogue]
```

where

```
encapsulation := delimiter transport-padding
                 CRLF body-part
```

Although RFC 2046 includes two, apparently different, rules for `body-part`, viz. [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#page-23) and [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#page-43), it seems `body-part` may be empty (also see `MIME-part-headers` in [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#page-8) and `message` in [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#appendix-B.1)). In addition, `transport-padding` should be empty.

Assuming this is the case, then `encapsulation` with an empty `body-part` would be `delimiter CRLF`.

I guess this would make "part 4" officially empty.

As for "part 5", based on the above, I would expect the stream to end in `encapsulation close-delimiter`, so that would be  `delimiter CRLF close-delimiter`.

However, the stream ("part 5") ends in `delimiter close-delimiter`, without a `CRLF` (I assume this is the "missing a CRLF" from the question title).

Doesn't this mean the stream is simply invalid (or non-compliant)?